# Sqlite update work on simulator but do not work on device

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I want to update my table.This code work on simulator but does not work on device. I found that I can't write to any files in my app bundle but I do not how change it to work. Please help me.

```
-(NSString *)filePath
{ 
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSError *error;
    bool success;
    NSString *writablePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writablePath error:&error];   
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",writablePath);
    return   writablePath;
}
```

And Then:

```
- (IBAction)addToFavorite:(id)sender
    {
        [self filePath];
        sqlite3_stmt *updateStatement=nil;
        NSString *sql=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"UPDATE A SET favorite=? WHERE x='%@' ",mystring];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &updateStatement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 1, [@"1" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
        if (sqlite3_step(updateStatement)!=SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSAssert(0,@"Error While Creating Update Statement. '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }
        sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);     
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh. I have had this problem before. COPY your test.sqlite database. Rename it to Test2.sqlite, and copy it back over. Do a clean. Update your source code to become test2.sqlite And run it again. Sounds screwy, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: You have somehow found more or less the right code to set up your database by copying it from bundle to writable space.  You need to trace the execution of that code to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: A device is case-sensitive. If your file really named "Test.sqlite" and not "test.sqlite" (or some other variation)?

Comment: You need to add an `else` to your check on `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. Also check the result of opening the database (before to use `sqlite3_open_v2`).

Comment: I encounter Error in Return writablePath line. the Error is "attempt to write a readonly database"

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error While Creating Update Statement. 'attempt to write a readonly database''

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have made changes in simulator, but on device new database have not been updated.

Just delete your app from device and re-run it i.e.

> CLEAN INSTALL